# Tensorflow: Save evaluation metrics

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've trained, in a distributed way, a logistic regression model using the tensorflow canned model `tf.Estimator.LogisticClassifier`.
A checkpoint is created every X seconds and an evaluation is performed on each checkpoint.

Is is possible to save evaluation metrics obtained with each checkpoint ?

I noticed that evaluation metrics might be already saved but I did not figure out where they could be saved and how to read them:

```
INFO:tensorflow:Saving dict for global step 2000: accuracy = 1.0, accuracy_baseline = 1.0, auc = 1.0, auc_precision_recall = 0.0, average_loss = 0.0060327444, global_step = 2000, label/mean = 0.0, loss = 1.5422962, precision = 0.0, prediction/mean = 0.005973566, recall = 0.0
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you specified a model_dir, the metrics are saved in this directory. If you didn't specify explicitly, a directory in /tmp/ will be assigned and this dir name will be printed in the log.

You can visualize the saved metrics using tensorboard with:

```
tensorboard --logdir /path/to/your/model_dir
```